# How to insert a value from a select statement into a table along with a hardcoded value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have a table called **ROLES** with **ROLEID** and **ROLEDESC** as the columns.
I am trying to get the **max ROLEID** from **ROLES** table and store it in another table along with a hardcoded value say **'NEWROLEDESC'**

The new table(viz. 'DROLES') structure is: **DID** and **DROLEDESC** where **DROLEDESC** is to be populate with a hardcoded value and **DID** is to populated with a value from the select statement : `SELECT MAX(ROLEID)+1 as maxroleid FROM ROLES`

I have tried :

```
insert into DROLES(DID) SELECT MAX(ROLEID)+1 FROM ROLES
```

now,the above inserts the max ID in the DID, but when I try

```
insert into DROLES(DID,DROLEDESC) 
values ((SELECT MAX(ROLEID)+1 FROM ROLES),'NEWROLEDESC')
```

It doesn't work.Ofcourse the SQL grammer is not correct. Is there any way to achieve it/The correct SQL Syntax?

**NOTE**: I am just writing this as an experiment. I know AUTO increment would do the trick.Anything apart from that?

Comment: `insert into DROLES(DID, DROLEDESC) SELECT MAX(ROLEID)+1, 'NEWROLEDESC' FROM ROLES` Be aware of errors that concurrent queries may cause. Reinventing `AUTO_INCREMENT` is not the best way to go.

Comment: Ahh...Just the thing I was looking for. The correct SQL syntax! :)
Thanks a ton!
Thanks for the suggestion too! Just asked this for learning purpose!

Comment: @lad2025 , you are really fast :) how can wrote it in answer if you already solve it using comment .. haha , 1 upvote for the comment ^^

Comment: Serves the purpose either way! :D
*Cheers*

Comment: @lad2025 upvoted done too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reinventing `AUTO_INCREMENT(MySQL)/SEQUENCE/IDENTITY(SQL Server)` is not the best way to go and you may end up with incorrect values with concurent queries!**

The [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO DROLES(DID, DROLEDESC) 
SELECT MAX(ROLEID)+1, 'NEWROLEDESC' 
FROM ROLES;
```

Keep in mind that if you insert multiple times to `DROLES` and `ROLES` is not chaning you will get the same value in `DID` column.